# question about homology theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In the book Griffiths and Harris，when calculate the Homology group of a manifold with boundary，they claim that the connecting map of homology group by taking the boundary of the manifold. How to prove it？

And when the $n-1$ th homology group of the manifold with dimension $n$ is trivial，then every $n-1$ submanifold is the boundary of some manifold ,how to prove it? （Jason DeVito give a counterexample on the comments ，but I still wander that ，can we add some condition to make this claims work？）

Comment: what's the regular one?

Comment: The last paragraph doesn't work:  $H_2(\mathbb{R}^3) = 0$, $\mathbb{R}P^3$ contains $\mathbb{R}P^2$, but $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is not the boundary of any manifold.

Comment: @AndresMejia Maybe I should say that how to prove the connecting map is just taking the boundary of the manifold.

Comment: @JasonDeVito yes,you are right, thank you for your counterexample.